# Вычитание 2-х сумм в SQL

Tags: sql

[image: table]
**Есть 2 селект запроса:**
мне нужно посчитать :

```
select SUM (amount) from transaction where to_account_id=14; -> сумма всех
входящих трансзакций
select SUM (amount) from transaction where from_account_id=14; -> сумма всех 
исходящих трансзакций
```

Нужно вычесть обе этих суммы - этот результат должен инсертнуться в поле другой таблицы
Я чет не понимаю как это по-SQL'ному написать...

P.S.  `PostgreSQL`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6083132/postgresql-insert-into-select

Comment: попробуй `(sum(amount) over to_account_id) - (sum(amount) over from_account_id)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все определенно просто:

```
SELECT OUTPUT.sum - INPUT.sum AS "Разница между суммами" 
FROM (SELECT SUM(amount) sum 
    FROM transaction 
    WHERE to_account_id=14) OUTPUT, 
    (SELECT SUM(amount) sum 
    FROM transaction 
    WHERE to_account_id=14) INPUT;
```

Comment: @prista Отметьте ответ плиз галочкой